# Changing URL using htaccess for seo

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I am trying to make SEO friendly, my URL is https://example.com/blog/single.php?blog=BLOG_TITLE&id=27, I want to make it https://example.com/blog/single.php/BLOG_TITLE.

From id in URL, I am fetching blog details using ajax from the database.

code I wrote to redirect page

```
function blogSingle(heading, id ){
            if(id){
                location.href = "https://example.com/blog/single.php? 
                 blog="+heading.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-')+"&id="+id+""
            }
        }
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Are all your blog titles unique? And do you have a mechanism to make sure they always will be?

Comment: The regular expression you are using now could lead to some problems because you're replacing many different characters by a single one. See: [JavaScript RegExp \s Metacharacter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp).

Comment: Have you ever created a rewrite rule in htaccess before?

Comment: Finally: I doubt not having `&id=27` in your URL will do any wonders on the SEO front.

Comment: I don't have much experience with rewriting rules, Yes all titles are unique and I can remove the id but after that how I will read the title from the URL if I have a URL like this  https://example.com/blog/single.php/BLOG_TITLE.?

Comment: You can't use JavaScript in .htaccess.  I'm not sure where your code is supposed to go.

Comment: I am not using js in htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .htaccess file, I assume you are using Apache.

You may want to use the `mod_rewrite` module to realise URL rewriting.

Here is an example how to do that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04